# .join() after exception occurred in main() thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

Learning C++ Thread support library. Using Visual Studio Professional 2013, and tested the code using MS compiler and Intel's latest C++ compiler.

Wrote small test program to test out exception handling. Idea is to simulate exception that occurs in the main thread, catch the exception and join another thread to main thread.

```
std::thread t(foo); //foo is just a function that prints a message

try
{
    //std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    throw  std::exception();
}
catch (const std::exception& e)
{
    std::cout << ".join after exception !\n";
    t.join();
}
std::cout << ".join in main() !\n";
//t.join()
```

However, at runtime, it throws the error:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library
---------------------------
Debug Error!

Program: ...al studio 2013\Projects\CPP_nonexcept\Debug\CPP_nonexcept.exe

R6010

- abort() has been called
```

Why ?

**Edit:** As was pointed out in comments, my code is incorrect, I have changed the code accordingly. However, I keep getting exactly same error as before.

Comment: You need to throw an `std::exception` for your catch block to work.

Comment: The "new" at the throw is wrong. That would be a pointer (to exception), and it wouldn´t be deleted anywhere too.

Comment: (and it´s probably better to catch a *const* exception *reference*, but that´s not required to work)

Comment: I don't think you're allowed to join the same thread twice.

Comment: @BenVoigt even changing the code as juanchopanza noted below, and commenting out second `.join`, I am getting an error.

Comment: Run it inside the debugger and check the call stack.  Where in your program does it go bad?

Answer (score 4):

You are throwing a pointer to exception and catching an exception by value. The types don'y match so the exception isn't caught. Throw an exception object (and catch by reference):

```
try
{
  throw  std::exception();
}
  catch (const std::exception& e)
{
  ....
```

Now you will catch the exception, joining the thread in the `catch` block. This means that you cannot join the thread again, it is not *joinable* anymore. See [`std::thread::join`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join).

Comment: I followed your advice, and changed my code accordingly, but I am still getting same error.

Comment: @newprint You join the thread in the catch block, rendering it not joinable. Then you try to join it agian...

Comment: I took out second `.join` that follows `catch`. Same error. Though, now it prints the message within `catch` statement.

Comment: @newprint Then you should post a new question with a minimal test case that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Why post a new question, if error and all the information related to the question are already given ?

Comment: @newprint anyway, I can't reproduce the problem. It works fine for me with a simple `foo` function.

Comment: Are you using VS 2013 -64 bit as well ?

Comment: @newprint Fortunately not.

Comment: Not sure what compiler you are running, but I have compiled project using Intel's latest C++ compiler as well as VS build in compiler, but keep getting same error.